# Magento 2.2.2 - InstallSchema.php - update multiple tables

Tags: magento2, database, install-script, magento2.2.2

While developing a new extension, I'm trying to update two tables at installation time by using `Setup\InstallSchema.php`. The tables are "admin_user" and "customer_entity", and I basically need the same fields for both of them.

The `InstallSchema.php` is triggered, but the tables don't get updated.

Please see the code & info below:

```
namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table;

class InstallSchema implements InstallSchemaInterface
{
    protected $installer;

    public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $this->installer = $setup;
        $this->installer->startSetup();

        $this->addUsersFields('admin_user');
        $this->addUsersFields('customer_entity');

        $this->installer->endSetup();
    }

    protected function addUsersFields($table)
    {
        $table = $this->installer->getTable($table);

        $this->installer->getConnection()->addColumn(
            $table,
            'field1',
            [
                'type' => Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                'nullable' => false,
                'default' => 'field1Default',
                'length' => '45',
                'comment' => 'comment'
            ]
        );

        $this->installer->getConnection()->addColumn(
            $table,
            'field2',
            [
                'type' => Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                'nullable' => false,
                'default' => 'field2Default',
                'length' => '45',
                'comment' => 'comment'
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

> EDITED: updated fields name correctly : field1 and field2

Using Magento 2.2.2 on AWS, from an AWS AMI. Developer mode enabled.

I'm running :

1. `php bin/magento module:enable ModuleName` (works fine, tells me that
   has enabled the module)
2. `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` (works fine, I can see the module in the output)
3. `php bin/magento setup:di:compile` (works fine)

I've :

1. made sure the `InstallSchema.php` is included each time by deleting
   the module entry from "setup_module" table;
2. tested that it's
   triggered by deliberately deleting an ";" from a line, and within
   `php bin/magento setup:di:compile` it shows an error message and the
   process is stopped.

So basically I'm 100% sure the `InstallSchema.php` is triggered.

THE PROBLEM is that the tables don't get updated, nor do I get any error message. Neither anything worth mentioned in exception.log, system.log or /var/log/apache2/error.log.

Any way to debug this?

Answer (score 0):

You need do add installer in passsing parameter instead of table.

```
protected function addUsersFields($installer){}
```

and get table name code like:

```
$tableName = $installer->getTable('tablename');
```

Comment: the installer is already set:

$this->installer = $setup;

Answer (score 0):

You have included **`field1`** two times in the **`addUsersFields`** function while adding column in **`addColumn`** 2nd argument. Lets change it to **`field2`** then check the table...

```
protected function addUsersFields($table)
{
    $table = $this->installer->getTable($table);

    $this->installer->getConnection()->addColumn(
        $table,
        'field1',
        [
            'type' => Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            'nullable' => false,
            'default' => 'field1Default',
            'length' => '45',
            'comment' => 'comment'
        ]
    );

    $this->installer->getConnection()->addColumn(
        $table,
        'field2',
        [
            'type' => Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            'nullable' => false,
            'default' => 'field2Default',
            'length' => '45',
            'comment' => 'comment'
        ]
    );
}
```

Comment: No no, that's just a typo I've made here. field1 and field2 you see here, are just bogus field names.

In the original script,  all the fields are different and their name written correctly.

Comment: did you check error log? and apache log?

Comment: I've monitored exception.log, system.log and /var/log/apache2/error.log . Nothing.